# Google chart colors disappeared on live project but works good in offline

Tags: javascript, php

After uploading local laravel project to godaddy website, the chart colors are disappeared.

I created a google pie chart in laravel and it works well. I have uploaded my project to live. But in live the google pie chart is not loading

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var analytics1 = <?php echo $alliance; ?>;
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
            /* call pie chart1*/
            function drawChart1()
            {
            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics1);
            var options1 = {
                title:'2014 National Alliance data',
                chartArea:{right:0,top:0,width:"120%",height:"120%"},
                pieHole:0.4,
                legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'start' },
                };
            var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
            chart1.draw(data1, options1);
            }
</script>
```

The chart is completely grayed out with single color.
[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJWU3.png)

Below is the image in local project
[image]

Comment: Try to remove `http:` and `https:` from cdn urls for css and js libraries you have loaded just keep // at the start.

Comment: I tried removing http: & https: - but not working. Is it some thing I have to register my website with google to use google pie charts